# Android ListView Pagination for huge data

Tags: android, pagination, android-listview

I am doing a project which is loading lot of data from the server. I have to get that data and arrange it in a listview along with the images. i am facing problem with large data, As the number of values getting increase my app is taking too much time to load.

How can i do pagination for this. i tried [this](http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/) but i did not get what to do..
Anyone please help me in doing this.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: How many number of rows your inserting? which adapter your using? What is data about? Share your coding.

Comment: i am using custom adapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomClass>, the data is containing about a user information like name, details, profile pis, recent chat....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions available for so-called "endless" lists. You linked to one. Here is mine: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless. There are a few more floating around, IIRC.

Comment: I tried this, but this is loading data from our information, i need it to be dynamic... Like i have to call a url for data, i need to get suppose 10 from that service and when i go to end it should load next 10

Comment: @wolverine: That is precisely the model used by my `EndlessAdapter`, from the project at the above link.

Comment: I am fresh to this task, I have single web service which will return all data one time, i am not getting this to do. please help me with some source code.